# Last created DIV to be above other DIVs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating DIVs dynamically and appending them to a particular DIV.

My question is how do I always make the last created DIV to be above other DIVs within the appended (its parent) DIV?

So basically I want the last created DIV to be on the top level of the other.

```
DIV 4 - [created at 4:32pm]
DIV 3 - [created at 4:29pm]
DIV 2 - [created at 4:27pm]
DIV 1 - [created at 4:26pm]
```

the dynamic DIV css:

```
.dynamicDIV{
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

the append DIV css:

```
.parentDiv{
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

I'm not referring to the `z-index`. I want to position it above the others.

Comment: I don't know if I get it right, but have you tried `.prepend()` instead of `.append()` ?

Comment: give some real html and jquery

Comment: @empiric: thanks. that worked. Post your answer and I shall accept. You're the first to spot it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I pointed out in my comment, `.prepend()` can be used here:

```
 $('.parentDiv').prepend('<div class="dynamicDIV">New Div</div>');
```

but there is a second possibilty:

```
$('<div />').addClass('dynamicDIV').text('New Div').prependTo('.parentDiv');
```

This solution is a bit more maintainable.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/aq3zyv9L/)

**Reference**

[.prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

[.prependTo()](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/)

Comment: @Fergoso thanks, You're welcome, as a tip, have a closer look on my second solution, as I found it more maintainable and cleaner.

Comment: thanks. when use prependTo() why doesn't `$('#dynamicDIVid').focus();` work?

Comment: I would assume that you need even-[delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) here, because you are creating dynamic dom-elements.

Answer (score 2):

```
var parentElement; 
var newFirstElement; 

parentElement.insertBefore(newFirstElement, parentElement.firstChild);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .prepend() on whatever element you want to be preceeded with the new one:

http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

Answer (score 0):

When a DIV is at `position: absolute`, the last sibling in the DOM is over the others. This doesn't depend on the time you inserted it.
But you can override this behavior by using `z-index: 1`.

Look at this HTML code:

```
<style>
  div.container > div {position: absolute; z-index: 0}
  div#C {z:index: 7}
</style>
<div class="container">
  <div id="A">A</div>
  <div id="B">B</div>
  <div id="C">C</div>
  <div id="D">D</div>
</div>
```

This code will display **C** hidding **D**, hidding **B**, hidding **A**.

Answer (score 0):

CSS with `display:flex` and `flex-direction:column-reverse;` can help you:

```css
body {/* parent container of div to shw in a reverse flow*/
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column-reverse; /* row-reverse if on line*/
  }
div {
  width:50%;
  border:solid;
  margin:auto;
  }
div:last-of-type:after {
  content:'last in document !';
  color:red;
  }
```

```html
<div> 1 </div>
<div> 2 </div>
<div> 3 </div>
<div> 4 </div>
```

anyway, in the DOM or for CSS selector, last will be last. reverse order only shows at screen.

Comment: awesome. But does not change the DOM, it just renders the divs in a reverse order

Comment: @FrancescoE. this is what i pointed at :) if you really want to reverse it, it should be done on server side, saved and send to browser.

Comment: well, you're partially right, you reverse the elements in the client side and then you can something else (if needed) with element reversed. Anyway it is awesome your CSS solution.